# ASUS USB-n13 dropping connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb, asus

I'm increasingly at a loss with Ubuntu. I bought a TP-Link TL-WN823N USB wi-fi dongle a couple months back, and had to unplug and plug it back in on every reboot to get it to work. So the other day, I gave up and bought an ASUS USB-N13, and it seemed like it worked fine for a day or two. But now it's simply dropping connection. The wi-fi signal seems to stay strong, but the connection dies. It's not the fiber-optic connection because other devices have no problem. Here's the output of the wireless-info thing I ran when the connection died a few minutes ago.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26213997/

When the connection dies, it simply hangs there for a minute or two, refusing to do anything. I've tried the USB-N13 on two different USB ports with no difference. Also: following a tip in a different forum or thread, I ran the command to change the power setting (?) from 3 to 2. Think this was in NetworkManager or a .conf file. No change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two changes. First, the driver for the unused TL-WN823N still loads. Let's blacklist it to prevent any possible conflicts. This can easily be reversed in the future if needed. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist 8192eu" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Also, there are two possibly conflicting drivers loaded for the ASUS USB-N13; let's try blacklisting one to see if stability improves:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

> Also: following a tip in a different forum or thread, I ran the
>   command to change the power setting (?) from 3 to 2. Think this was in
>   NetworkManager or a .conf file

Please verify that this is set correctly:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

If your setting is correct, the result will be:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Reboot and let us hear the result.